# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in react frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to access properties of an object from an array of objects I get after fetching them from backend bust as soon as I try to access the property ,it logs the object itself as undefined which was logged successfully if I never access the property in console.

here is the code and I commented where it gets the error:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";


const useGetConversations = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getConversations = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await fetch("/api/users");
                const data = await res.json();
                if (data.error) {
                    throw new Error(data.error);
                }
                
                setConversations(data);
                
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error(error.message);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
                
            }
        };

        getConversations();
    }, []);
    console.log("before return statement",conversations[0]);// it runs correctly only if i am not trying to acces any property
    console.log("before return statement",conversations[0].name);
    return { loading, conversations };
    
};
export default useGetConversations;
```

here are the error screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I expect to run the files successfully:

```js
import useGetConversations from "../../hooks/useGetConversations";
import { getRandomEmoji } from "../../utils/emojis";
import Conversation from "./Conversation";

const Conversations = () => {
    const { loading, conversations } = useGetConversations();

    //could log the array of objects succesfully
    // console.log(conversations);
    //could log a single object successfully
    // console.log(conversations[0]); 
    //could not log the object properties successfully and previous lines are also defined as undefined 
    // console.log(conversations[0].name); 
    return (
        <div className='py-2 flex flex-col overflow-auto'>
            {conversations.map((conversation, idx) => (
                <Conversation
                    key={conversation._id}
                    conversation={conversation}
                    emoji={getRandomEmoji()}
                    lastIdx={idx === conversations.length - 1}
                />
            ))}

            {loading ? <span className='loading loading-spinner mx-auto'></span> : null}
        </div>
    );
};
export default Conversations;
```

Comment: conversations are retrieved asynchronously, so before the network returns results, its length is 0. Directly accessing values by index will return 'undefined', and accessing a property of 'undefined' will result in an error. When accessing values, you should add some checks. Only perform value retrieval operations when 'conversations.length > 0' to avoid errors.

Comment: @JhonWill  First I am sure that my conversation object has at least 4 users. Also i tried the if statement and it worked for normal stattements but issue is same if i send it through prop to Conversation.jsx. It always receives undefined

Answer (score 1):

Use Optional chaining (?) to access when dealing with nested objects or when accessing properties of objects returned by API calls.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";


const useGetConversations = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getConversations = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await fetch("/api/users");
                const data = await res.json();
                if (data.error) {
                    throw new Error(data.error);
                }
                
                setConversations(data);
                
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error(error.message);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
                
            }
        };

        getConversations();
    }, []);
    console.log("before return statement",conversations[0]);
    console.log("before return statement",conversations[0]?.name);
    return { loading, conversations };
    
};
export default useGetConversations;
```

Comment: It worked but I still can't pass consversations as a prop using map() as I did in my above provided code for Conversations.jsx. On the recevieing end it still says undefined:

Comment: Check conversations length before mapping conversations.length && conversations.map(() =>....)

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to do a conditional rendering of the component. If the hook useGetConversations retrieved empty, the component which uses the hook will do something like:

```html
if (conversations.length === 0) {
  return <Fallback />
}
```

Fallback being some kind of auxiliar component, just like a loading would do. I think optional chaining is okay, but I would not recommend using it everytime. Code can get very messy working with complex objects.